# Sharepoint 2007 : Custom ListViewer WebPart Across SiteCollection

Tags: sharepoint-2007

What is the best way to create a custom List Viewer Webpart which query accross Site Collection which are under two different Web Application and running under different identity. Also on click it should display that item too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go for code...
i dont knw any out of box feature that can query between two web apps.

Comment: I know OOTB there is no solution. I am looking for custom solution and any direction will be really helpful an appreciated.